# Change values from nominal to real in LM portion of ISLM?

Tags: inflation

Given $ M / P = L(Y, i) $, where $M/P$ is the real money supply, and $Y$ is GDP, $i$ being the interest rate, we know that this equation makes demand of money equal to supply of money. Therefore, could we use $M$ instead of $M/P$ for nominal supply of money, and consider nominal instead of real GDP, and therefore find nominal instead of real interest rates? In what way do these variables relate in that sense?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, $i$ is used to denote the nominal interest rate for the LM equation, so
$\frac{M}{P}=L(Y,i)$ shows a relationship between real money supply $\left(\frac{M}{P}\right)$, real GDP $(Y)$, and nominal interest rate $(i)$.

The real and nominal interest rate are related in the following way:$\quad i=r-\pi^e$
Therefore, if expected inflation $(\pi^e)$ is 0, then there is no distinction between the nominal interest rate and the real interest rate.

Now if you rewrite the LM equation as: $M=PL(Y,i)$ you will get a relationship between the nominal money supply $(M)$ , nominal GDP $(PY)$ , and the nominal interest rate $(i)$

For example, suppose Money Demand function is: $L(Y,i)=\frac{Y}{i}$
then LM curve is given by $\frac{M}{P}=\frac{Y}{i}$ but we can use the above transformation to express the relationship in nominal terms, i.e., we can rewrite $M=\frac{PY}{i}$

Comment: I am still not sure about your question, but I was hoping this answer is what you're looking for. If not let me know, I'll edit it accordingly